# Memory representation of union

Tags: c, unions

i wrote this simple program to check the memory representation of union variable.

```
int main()
{
    short s=0x7080;
    union{
        char c;
        short s;
    }un1={s};
    printf(" %#X",un1.s);
    return 0;
}
```

output : `0X80`

memory representation of un1 `0x0045FE3C  80 00`. I was expecting it to be `0x0045FE3C  80 70`
Why is the variable `s` not holding `'80 70'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the variable s not holding '80 70' ?

Because you initialized `c`, not `s`. The initialization assumes that you set the first element, so

```
un1 = {s};
```

means "convert `s` to `char`, then assign it to `un1.c`, because `c` is the first element of the `union`.

If you want to assign it to `s`, use designated initializer:

```
un1 = {.s = s};
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2RZ5AU) (prints `0X7080`, as expected).